# Ajax multiple value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Did anyone know how i can send all this stuff with ajax to a search.php? it is already working but only with a search bar. I want to add to the search bar these variables. Its only important for the sort variable(the div with the sort id) to send the data on the beginning.
i think it would work to save the var into divs and get the values with `document.getElementById('').getAttribute('value')` but i still need to find out how to add this line of code to this ajax and that the ajax constantly check for changes in this divs. i still want that the ajax file send a output before i even touched the searchbar and the divs

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    load_data();
    function load_data(query)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"search.php",
            method:"post",
            data:{search:query},
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
        var search = $(this).val();
        if(search != '')
        {
            load_data(search);
        }
        else
        {
            load_data();            
        }
    });
});
```

```
function gettagValue() {
    var checks = document.getElementsByClassName('tag');
    var strtag = '';

    for ( i = 0; i<checks.length; i++) {
        if ( checks[i].checked === true ) {
            str += checks[i].value + "#";
        }
    }
    alert(strtag);
}
```

```
function getblacklistValue() {
    var checks = document.getElementsByClassName('blacklist');
    var strblacklist = '';

    for ( i = 0; i<checks.length; i++) {
        if ( checks[i].checked === true ) {
            strblacklist += checks[i].value + "#";
        }
    }
    alert(strblacklist);
}
```

```
function getbrandValue() {
    var checks = document.getElementsByClassName('brand');
    var strbrand = '';

    for ( i = 0; i<checks.length; i++) {
        if ( checks[i].checked === true ) {
            strbrand += checks[i].value + "#";
        }
    }
    alert(strbrand);
}
```

```
 alert(document.getElementById('sort').getAttribute('value'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to send the values you're currently `alert`ing?  For starters, return those values instead of just `alert`ing them:

```
function gettagValue() {
    // ...
    return strtag;
}

// same for the getblacklistValue and getbrandValue functions
```

Then in your AJAX code, call those functions to get those values and include them in the data:

```
function load_data(query)
{
    let tagValue = gettagValue();
    let blacklistValue = getblacklistValue();
    let brandValue = getbrandValue();
    $.ajax({
        url:"search.php",
        method:"post",
        data:{
            search:query,
            tagValue:tagValue,
            blacklistValue:blacklistValue,
            brandValue:brandValue
        },
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: good to know how to set the vars public but it dosent work. The alert function was for me to check. it doesnt exist in the final version

Comment: @frederik: What specifically isn't working?  When you debug, do your functions return the values you expect?  Are those values being included in the request to the server?  What specifically is failing?

Comment: the ajax isnt working. i dont get an output. when i whange the ajax the whole js file isnt working anymore and all the other functions dont load

Comment: @frederik: You're going to have to be more specific.  The question is about how to send these values to the server.  Are the values being sent to the server?  Check the Network tab in your browser's debugging tools to see the AJAX request being sent.  If it contains the values then the code is working.  If, however, your *server-side* code is failing in some way, that's a separate issue entirely.

Comment: that was my bad. i messed up the file and got a syntax error. Now i get feedback of the ajax but i cant input something

Comment: @frederik: Why can't you?  Once again, how is it failing?  This is a good opportunity for you to begin familiarizing yourself with your browser's debugging tools to observe errors, use the script debugger, observe network requests/responses, etc.  Just saying "I changed something and it doesn't work" tells others exactly nothing about the problem.  We can only help if we can see the problem.

Comment: the ajax file sends data once. it doesnt matter if it is hardcoded or not it is ignoring the other vars

Comment: @frederik: So the correct values are being sent to the server but the server is responding with incorrect results?  If that's the case then it sounds like you need to start looking at your server-side code.

Comment: nvm i make somuch stupid mistakes right now. it is reacting on the hardcoded stuff i forgot to replace the let with var. but it is sending data only once, but i removed the `.ready(function()`. it is not responding to later inputs